# Eclipse on x64 Fedora

Tags: android, eclipse, fedora

I have installed eclipse and android SDK on Fedora 17. In eclipse I got this error

> /home/jakub/Android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I tried install this packages: ncurses-libs.i686 libstdc++.i686 libgcc.i686, but always got that error

Answer (score 1):

i got it working on 64bit CentOS using a stackexchange answer i cannot find at the moment.  It basically involved appending .i686 to several package names, ie:

```
yum install libstdc++.i686
```

ia32-libs does not formally exist as an rpm.  However, on my Ubuntu 10.04 box

```
dpkg --listfiles ia32-libs | wc
```

indicates there are 1456 files in ia32-libs to make 32bit stuff work on 64bit Debian based platforms.  i certainly did not install 1456 .i686 packages.  So just now, i entered

```
    $ rpm -qa | grep i686
        libX11-1.3-2.el6.i686   
        libstdc++-4.4.6-4.el6.i686   
        openssl-1.0.0-25.el6_3.1.i686   
        libXau-1.0.5-1.el6.i686   
        SDL-1.2.14-3.el6.i686   
        glibc-2.12-1.80.el6_3.7.i686   
        libgcc-4.4.6-4.el6.i686   
        libxcb-1.5-1.el6.i686   
        libXrandr-1.3.0-4.el6.i686   
        zlib-1.2.3-27.el6.i686   
        libselinux-2.0.94-5.3.el6.i686   
        openssl-devel-1.0.0-25.el6_3.1.i686   
        nss-softokn-freebl-3.12.9-11.el6.i686   
        ncurses-libs-5.7-3.20090208.el6.i686    
        krb5-libs-1.9-33.el6_3.3.i686    
        libXext-1.1-3.el6.i686   
        libcom_err-1.41.12-12.el6.i686   
        libXrender-0.9.5-1.el6.i686   
        keyutils-libs-1.4-4.el6.i686
```

When i find the original answer i used, i will post it back here.

Answer (score 0):

did you used android in fedora before.?

System requirements

**Operating Systems**

- Windows XP (32-bit), Vista (32- or 64-bit), or Windows 7 (32- or 64-bit)
- Mac OS X 10.5.8 or later (x86 only)
- Linux (tested on Ubuntu Linux, Lucid Lynx)
  GNU C Library (glibc) 2.7 or later is required.
  On Ubuntu Linux, version 8.04 or later is required.
  64-bit distributions must be capable of running 32-bit applications.

[link:](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Requirements)

Answer (score 0):

because SDK is 32bit

try to use: yum install ia32-libs